# Python equivalent of Java's Redirect.INHERIT

Tags: java, python, subprocess, processbuilder

I am trying to replicate the following script written in Java in Python, but I am not seeing a equivalent of Redirect.INHERIT in Python. What would be the correct approach for porting this?

```
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;

public class TestProcessBuilder {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("fairymax");
            builder.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT);
            builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
            builder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);

            Process subProcess = builder.start();
            subProcess.waitFor();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation of [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) has all you need.

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect.INHERIT` is the default in Python. To emulated the Java code in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

rc = subprocess.call("fairymax")
```

Answer (score 0):

The subprocess's Popen.communicate() method does the same thing as the submitted block of code.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("fairymax").communicate()
```

I have tested this and it works with Python but not Jython.

Comment: there is no need to call `.communicate()` unless you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr (if you don't see `subprocess.PIPE` in the code; do not call `.communicate()`).